# sklearn memory error for kfold CV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to train my dataset which is 13159 instance and use bag of words feature matrix, the number of feature is 18800

My code worked well when I didn't use 10-fold cv, even training the whole dataset.
But when I used 10 fold cv index, it gave me memory error

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
train_data = np.array(data_content[train_index])MemoryError
```

I don't think this dataset is too huge to break down memory space. My laptop is 4GB RAM and 64-bit

```
'''Cross-Validation'''
skf = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(data_label, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
'''For each fold, Do the classification'''
for train_index, test_index in skf:
    print(type(data_content))
    print (type(data_label))
    train_data = np.array(data_content[train_index])
    train_label = np.array(data_label[train_index])
    test_data = np.array(data_content[test_index])
    test_label = np.array(data_label[test_index])
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the variables followed by garbage collection at end of each iteration works for me every time. Leaving it here if it helps anyone.

```
del train_data 
del train_label
del test_data 
del test_label
gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire your code using nohup and check your cpu utilization. In Linux, this can be done using

```
htop
```

My guess is, you cpu will be utilized 100%.

To solve this, you can reduce your features or go for out of core feature extraction method. I would prefer these from sklearn:

[- PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

[- L1 Regularization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html)

[- FeatutreVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html)

[- Out of core feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html)

There will be many more.

Comment: I checked my cpu which is well even running the code, but my RAM is jump to 90%, not to 100%. the weird thing is using whole data to train is fine, but using CV to split dataset by index into 10 fold is wrong.

Comment: Yeah so that may be one of the reasons. At some point of time, RAM would be completely utilized.

Comment: Thx@Pappu Jha,  I added some codes to clean the array at the end of each loop, it worked and no memory error, I don't know why, but glad it worked.

Comment: Cool. Request you to add those improvements and edit your code. It  will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

at the end of each loop, I added the following codes, no memory error:

```
train_data = []
train_label = []
test_data = []
test_label = []
```